# Targeting links with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

This is pretty much an add on to a question I posted before about loading an external page without ajax, but keeping it an iOS web app window. What I came up with for that example was this

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  $("#test").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign("test.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

But now what I want to do is to set this up for every link I would have on that page. Seeing as I don't know how many links I could have, it would be very tedious to do this every time I add a new link. So I found this snippet and thought I could combined the two some how, I just need some direction on how.

```
$('a').each(function(index){
var elementId=$(this). attr("id");
elementId='#'=elementId;
```

So for each a tag or href on my page, it will automatically grab the link and load it in that particular manner automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can combine your codes. Anyway I haven't tried your code but you have to wrap an .each() function around your click events. Also you should give every clickable link a the same class. Should look like this:

```
$('.class').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign("test.html");
  })
});
```

if you now want those links to link on different pages you can define a data-href attribute on each link. like this: `data-href="test2.html"` in your html.
You can now use

```
$(this).data("href");
```

and put the output into a variable. Afterwards you can place it in your window.location.assign thing dynamically.

Hope I understood your problem and it helped.

Comment: After some digging and researching, I came up with this. It combings what I provided before and your previous post. 

**<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  $('a').each(function (index){
   var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
   elementId= elementId + '.html';
 $(function(){
 $(elementId).click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.assign(elementId);
 });
 });
  });
});
</script>**